# Make a pie chart for sum of a variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart

I am trying to make a pie chart. I am facing an issue in which the colors are filled by the group but the pie also has lines that separate each measure individually instead of by group.

This is my code:

```
ggplot(Book1, aes(x="", y=Eb_impact_value, fill=area))+ geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1, color="white") + coord_polar("y", start=0) + theme_void()
```

My data follows the following structure:

[image]

And this is the pie chart which results from my code:

[image]

Comment: You need to sum up your data by the groups you wish before creating the plot.

Answer (score 0):

You have not given a very good reproducible example, but what I advice you to do is to first group by column 1, sum values of Column3 , then merge with the new dataframe and delete. I do not know the full name of column 3 but check the code and change it for the name:

```
library(dplyr)

#Assuming your df is called Book1 as in your code: 
new_df <- Book1 %>%
  group_by(Area) %>%
  summarise(Column3_Sum = sum(Column3))

final_df <- merge(Book1, new_df, by = "Area") %>%
  select(-Impact)
```